# Check if Python list elements are in a Pandas dataframe row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

My question might be easy but I can't find the solution quickly.
I have a dataframe 'df' and I want to check if elements in my list 'list' exist in any row of df.

This is a df example:

[image]

And this is my_list example:

[image]

In this case, I want to get row 2 of df as all elements in my_list exist in that row.

Thanks

Comment: simply do,consider df as your dataframe,   df.iloc[2]  here 2 is row index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way using [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df.loc[df.applymap(lambda x: x in names).sum(1).eq(len(names))]

    Color  Number Code  Flag
2  Yellow      19   ee     0
```

Comment: I am wondering if it also matched the order of element appearance in the list with the order in df row. I mean back to back order, is it checked also?

Answer (score 2):

You can try pandas [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

```
df.loc[df.isin(my_list).astype(int).sum(axis=1) == len(my_list), :]
```

where my_list being your list of searches you want to perform.

NOTE: In case you want a partial match you can play around with the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Similar question has been asked before. [link to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55745235/how-to-check-if-all-the-elements-in-list-are-present-in-pandas-column)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Color':['Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Purple','Orange'], 
    'Number':[20, 21, 19, 18, 40],
    'Code':['ss', 'dd', 'ee', 'xx', 'tt'],
    'Flag':[1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
})

names = set(['Yellow', 0, 'ee'])

m = [names.issubset(i) for i in df.values.tolist()]

print(df[m])
```

Comment: print(df.loc[[names.issubset(i) for i in df.values.tolist()]])

Answer (score 1):

[Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIJ1I.png)

```
import pandas as pd
data={'Color': ['Blue','Green','Yellow','Purple','Orange'],
      'Number':[20,21,19,18,40],
      'Code':['ss','dd','dd','xx','tt'],
      'Flag':[1,1,0,1,0]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
my_list=list(df.iloc[2])
print(my_list)
```

[Output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLjYq.png)