# Check if pandas column contains all elements from a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['a,b,c', 'a,c,f', 'b,d,f','a,z,c']})
```

And a list of items:

```
letters = ['a','c']
```

My goal is to get all the rows from `frame` that contain at least the 2 elements in `letters`

I came up with this solution:

```
for i in letters:
    subframe = frame[frame['a'].str.contains(i)]
```

This gives me what I want, but it might not be the best solution in terms of scalability.
Is there any 'vectorised' solution?
Thanks

Comment: It will give you only rows which contain the last letter because you override subframe in any iteration

Comment: @TomRon You're right, what a blunder :)

Comment: This works, wht if I want to match one or more elements. If I change the list as letters = ['a','c','m']. It should still match a and c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if all the elements in list are present in pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55745235/how-to-check-if-all-the-elements-in-list-are-present-in-pandas-column)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would build a list of Series, and then apply a vectorized `np.all`:

```
contains = [frame['a'].str.contains(i) for i in letters]
resul = frame[np.all(contains, axis=0)]
```

It gives as expected:

```
       a
0  a,b,c
1  a,c,f
3  a,z,c
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What will be the best solution if letters is a list of lists like [['a','c'], ['b','d']] and the value should match all the items in one of the sub-lists. Basically, value should contain ('a' and 'c') or ('b' and 'd'). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72273640/check-if-pandas-column-contains-all-values-from-any-list-of-lists

Answer (score 19):

One way is to split the column values into lists using [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), and check if `set(letters)` is a [`subset`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) of the obtained lists:

```
letters_s = set(letters)
frame[frame.a.str.split(',').map(letters_s.issubset)]

     a
0  a,b,c
1  a,c,f
3  a,z,c
​
```

---

Benchmark:

```
def serge(frame):
    contains = [frame['a'].str.contains(i) for i in letters]
    return frame[np.all(contains, axis=0)]

def yatu(frame):
    letters_s = set(letters)
    return frame[frame.a.str.split(',').map(letters_s.issubset)]

def austin(frame):
    mask =  frame.a.apply(lambda x: np.intersect1d(x.split(','), letters).size > 0)
    return frame[mask]

def datanovice(frame):
    s = frame['a'].str.split(',').explode().isin(letters).groupby(level=0).cumsum()
    return frame.loc[s[s.ge(2)].index.unique()]

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.concat([frame]*n, axis=0).reset_index(drop=True), 

    kernels=[
        lambda df: serge(df),
        lambda df: yatu(df),
        lambda df: df[df['a'].apply(lambda x: np.all([*map(lambda l: l in x, letters)]))],
        lambda df: austin(df),
        lambda df: datanovice(df),
    ],

    labels=['serge', 'yatu', 'bruno','austin', 'datanovice'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(0, 18)],
    equality_check=lambda x, y: x.equals(y),
    xlabel='N'
)
```

[image]

Comment: I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'` when i run your code? ran it on the provided frame aboe

Comment: What version? @Datanovice Double checking and all seems fine

Comment: my pandas is `1.0.3` and python is `3.7` probably just me

Comment: @Datanovice i think you need python 3.8 for this :)

Comment: Thanks, I get same error as @Datanovice and can not jump to python 3.8 unfortunately

Comment: @yatu I have a problem installing perfplot (base) C:\Users\Paisa>conda install -c conda-forge perfplot
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - perfplot

Current channels:

  - https://conda.....Please help...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What will be the best solution if letters is a list of lists like [['a','c'], ['b','d']] and the value should match all the items in one of the sub-lists. Basically, value should contain ('a' and 'c') or ('b' and 'd'). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72273640/check-if-pandas-column-contains-all-values-from-any-list-of-lists

Answer (score 10):

This also solves it:

```
frame[frame['a'].apply(lambda x: np.all([*map(lambda l: l in x, letters)]))]
```

Comment: This works, wht if I want to match one or more elements. If I change the list as letters = ['a','c','m']. It should still match a and c

Answer (score 9):

You can use `np.intersect1d`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

frame = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['a,b,c', 'a,c,f', 'b,d,f','a,z,c']})
letters = ['a','c']

mask =  frame.a.apply(lambda x: np.intersect1d(x.split(','), letters).size > 0)
print(frame[mask])

    a
0  a,b,c
1  a,c,f
3  a,z,c
```

Answer (score 8):

Use **set.issubset**:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['a,b,c', 'a,c,f', 'b,d,f','a,z,c','x,y']})
letters = ['a','c']

frame[frame['a'].apply(lambda x: set(letters).issubset(x))]

Out:

       a
0  a,b,c
1  a,c,f
3  a,z,c
```

Answer (score 5):

IIUC, `explode` and a boolean filter

the idea is to create a single series then we can groupby the index the count the true occurrences of your list using a cumulative sum

```
s = frame['a'].str.split(',').explode().isin(letters).groupby(level=0).cumsum()

print(s)

0    1.0
0    1.0
0    2.0
1    1.0
1    2.0
1    2.0
2    0.0
2    0.0
2    0.0
3    1.0
3    1.0
3    2.0
```

---

```
frame.loc[s[s.ge(2)].index.unique()]

out:

       a
0  a,b,c
1  a,c,f
3  a,z,c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
frame.iloc[[x for x in range(len(frame)) if set(letters).issubset(frame.iloc[x,0])]]
```

output:

```
        a
 0  a,b,c
 1  a,c,f
 3  a,z,c
```

timeit

```
%%timeit
#hermes
frame.iloc[[x for x in range(len(frame)) if set(letters).issubset(frame.iloc[x,0])]]
```

output

```
300 µs ± 32.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```