# str.contains multi values at the same time

Tags: python, pandas

i have some dataset `df` and i need check rows only with special values of strings in `name` column

so i need make `df[df.name.str.contains('John', regex=True)]`

this will outputs me df with John names

i can make logic OR like `df[df.name.str.contains('John|James', regex=True)]`

this will make me outputs df with John or James names

but how i can make contains with two values at the same time? for example we have name like James John Williams, and i need return only this row (string need contains John AND James)?

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60932036/check-if-pandas-column-contains-all-elements-from-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
df_out = df[df.name.str.contains('John', regex=True) & df.name.str.contains('James', regex=True)]
```

works both ways e.g John James / James John