# Check if one or more elements of a list are present in Pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

This question is an extension of the following question
[Check if pandas column contains all elements from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60932036/check-if-pandas-column-contains-all-elements-from-a-list)

In the question, for deriving output, all the members of a list are checked for a list in a Pandas column. My need is to check one or more elements of the list, i.e even if only one element of the list matches in the pandas column, I want to consider that in the output

The sample data would be

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['a,b,c', 'a,c,f', 'b,d,f','a,z,c']})


letters = ['a','c','m']
```

I want to get all the rows from the df where one or more elements of the letters list are found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change `issubset` to `isdisjoint` for found not common values, so then is added `~` for inverse mask:

```
letters = ['a','c','m']

letters_s = set(letters)
df = frame[~frame.a.str.split(',').map(letters_s.isdisjoint)]
print(df)
       a
0  a,b,c
1  a,c,f
3  a,z,c
```

Or first solution is possible modify by `np.any` for test at least one match:

```
contains = [frame['a'].str.contains(i) for i in letters]
df = frame[np.any(contains, axis=0)]
```