# Check if pandas column contains all values from any list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, filter

I have a data frame like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'B': ['red green blue', 'blue redorange', 'greenyellowgr','redz blue', 'redgreen 24wall']})
```

List of lists to be matched:

```
lsts = [['red','blue'], ['green', 'yellow']]
```

I need to get all the rows from df where column 'B' contains all the elements from any of the sub-lists. It should contain either both ('red' and 'blue') or contain both ('green' and 'yellow').
So, the output should look like

```
    A                B
0   1   red green blue
1   2   blue redorange
2   3   greenyellowgr
3   4   redz blue
```

What will be an optimal way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.str.findall` to convert characters in column B to lists then loop the `lsts` to use `set.issubset` to check if `lst` is subset of lists in column B. At last use `np.logical_or` to reduce the boolean list.

```py
import numpy as np

lsts = [['red','blue'], ['green', 'yellow']]

s = set(i for lst in lsts for i in lst)
bs = df['B'].str.findall('|'.join(s)).apply(set)

m = np.logical_or.reduce([bs.apply(set(lst).issubset) for lst in lsts])
```

```
print(df[m])

   A               B
0  1  red green blue
1  2  blue redorange
2  3   greenyellowgr
3  4       redz blue
```

Comment: Seems unnecessarily complicated ;) what's the point of the regex for example?

Comment: @mozway Overthinking the problem, spaces doesn't matter when converting to set.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh Thank you for the solution! However, the items in lsts need not be only characters, but it can be words, for which, this solution doesn't work. Sorry, I should have given a better example. I have updated my question now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use set operations:

##### words

```
lsts = [['red','blue'], ['green', 'yellow']]
sets = [set(l) for l in lsts]

import re
regex = '|'.join([re.escape(w) for l in lsts for w in l])

df[[any(S.issubset(x) for S in sets) for x in df['B'].str.findall(regex)]]
```

output:

```
   A               B
0  1  red green blue
1  2  blue redorange
2  3   greenyellowgr
3  4       redz blue
```

##### simple characters

```
lsts = [['a','c'], ['b', 'd']]
sets = [set(l) for l in lsts]

df[[any(S.issubset(x) for S in sets) for x in df['B']]]
```

Output:

```
   A      B
0  1  a b c
1  2   a cf
2  3    bdf
3  4   az c
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! However, the items in lsts need not be only characters, but it can be words, for which, this solution doesn't work. Sorry, I should have given a better example. I have updated my question now.

Comment: @ds_Abc this means you need to use a regex, but you have to be careful of ambiguous matches

Comment: eg. if you have both `red` and `are` as word and you find a string `cared`, which one would you keep?

Comment: have you checked the update?